# how to change start date of k8s api-server /other core component certificate system date change

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed a Kubernetes cluster v1.22.3 (`master`, `worker1`, `worker2`) on centos 7. After the installation I found out that my computer date/time is not correct. It was showing me 1 year ahead of current time.

When I have changed my date/time it started giving me error related to Kubernetes different component certificates as shown below

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-12-25T23:09:56Z is before 2022-12-08T18:55:46Z
```

Then I followed the method below to update the certificate but it only updated the expiration.

My steps are as below:

Step1: Check validity of certificate via `openssl command`:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -noout -text |grep ' Not '
```

---

```
        Not Before: Dec  8 18:55:46 2022 GMT
        Not After : Dec  8 18:55:46 2023 GMT
```

Step2: I have updated the certificate with the following command:

```
kubeadm certs check-expiration

kubeadm certs renew all

kubeadm certs check-expiration
```

Now I see it has updated the expiry date to `23 Dec 2022` from `8 Dec 2023` but start date is still the same - `8 Dec 2022`.

Is there any way I can update the start date of these certificates?

Comment: Is re-creation of the cluster is option for you? Because it will be the fastest. Or do you have limitations?

Comment: @Andrew Well I can re-create the cluster that is an option but I just want to give a try to solve this issue as it can happen again for some reason. So that is my point of view to solve this problem, currently I have searched a bit but cannot find any clue to update the certificates start date, every forum / discussion show up the way to renew expire certificate.

Comment: @Andrew well I got busy with other tasks and could not conclude the way forward, although I have applied one solution which ask me to remove all certificates but it does not change the start date. I need to remove all public / private keys and re-generate them again. But unfortunately I did not got time to go with this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Since we cannot update `Not Before` date, we can to regenerate the certificates.
Below are two possible ways how to solve it.

---

**Before starting, I suggest making a backup copy of the files located in  `/etc/kubernetes/` , `/var/lib/kubelet` folders and the `etcd` storage.**

---

**Solution 1 - Long way**

**On Master node**

1. Stop kubelet:
   `systemctl stop kubelet`
2. Remove folders:
   `rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/ /var/lib/kubelet/pki`
3. Stop running containers (commands will depend on the runtime you are using)
4. Execute initialization phases:

```
kubeadm init phase certs all
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all
kubeadm init phase kubelet-start
kubeadm init phase control-plane all
kubeadm init phase etcd local
kubeadm init phase upload-config all
kubeadm init phase mark-control-plane
kubeadm init phase bootstrap-token
kubeadm init phase kubelet-finalize all
```

If you receive an error **x509: certificate signed by unknown authority** while using `kubectl`, use the following commands:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Now master node should be in `Ready` status.

**On worker nodes**

1. Stop kubelet: `systemctl stop kubelet`
2. Remove folders with configs:

`rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/pki/ /etc/kubernetes/pki/ /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

3. Run command:

`kubeadm join phase kubelet-start \<master_node_ip>:6443 --token \<token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:\<hash>`

If you need a token, run this command on the master node:

`kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

Repeat this for all worker nodes.

When completed, all nodes should be in a `Ready` Status with new certificates.

---

**Solution 2 - Short way**

**On Master node**

1. Stop kubelet:
   `systemctl stop kubelet`
2. Remove folders:
   `rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/ /var/lib/kubelet/pki`
3. Stop running containers (commands will depend on the used runtime).
4. Run command:
   `kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd`
5. If you receive an error **x509: certificate signed by unknown authority** while using `kubectl`, use the following commands:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Now master node should be in `Ready` status.

**On worker nodes**

See the same part from  **Long way** solution.

---

**Additional materials.**
For a better understanding, the following materials may be helpful:

- Article [Breaking down and fixing Kubernetes](https://itnext.io/breaking-down-and-fixing-kubernetes-4df2f22f87c3)
- Information from Kubernetes website about [kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/)
- Article [Backup and Restore Kubernetes Etcd on the Same Control Plane Node](https://ystatit.medium.com/backup-and-restore-kubernetes-etcd-on-the-same-control-plane-node-20f4e78803cb)